# Substract one day Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, date

I would like to know how to remove one day from a specific date?
Example:

Date_Order
2021-04-18 09:15:22

How to transform it in 2021-04-17?

I'm trying to calculate the units that have been ordered yesterday.

Thanks a lot!! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just cast the timestamp to date, then subtract one day:

```sql
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT '2021-04-18 09:15:22'::timestamp AS Date_Order
)

SELECT Date_Order::date - INTERVAL '1 day' AS Date_Out
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo